Creating buffer circle to know which IDs fall within 1000 meters from a given point
My df is looks like this:



latitude
longitude
ID




-22.582779
29.080456
0


-22.582575
29.080794
1


41.758910
-53.626698
2


17.758527
-2.443443
3


-22.582699
29.080455
4



I wanna create a function which intake this above df and for each record it calculates the count and the corresponding IDs which falls within 100000 meters of radius.
R = 6371000  #earths' radius 

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    phi1, phi2 = radians(lat1), radians(lat2)
    delta_phi = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    delta_lambda = radians(lon2 - lon1)
    
    a = sin(delta_phi / 2)**2 + cos(phi1) * cos(phi2) * sin(delta_lambda / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    
    return R * c

def lat_lon_to_cartesian(lat, lon):
    lat, lon = np.radians(lat), np.radians(lon)
    x = R * np.cos(lat) * np.cos(lon)
    y = R * np.cos(lat) * np.sin(lon)
    z = R * np.sin(lat)
    return x, y, z

# Add Cartesian coordinates to the DataFrame
df['x'], df['y'], df['z'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: lat_lon_to_cartesian(row['lat'], row['lon']), axis=1))

# Build a KD-Tree for fast spatial indexing
tree = cKDTree(df[['x', 'y', 'z']])

# Function to find points within a 100000 meters radius using the KD-Tree
def points_within_radius_kdtree(lat, lon, radius=100000):
    x, y, z = lat_lon_to_cartesian(lat, lon)
    indices = tree.query_ball_point([x, y, z], radius / R)  # Adjust radius for Cartesian space
    nearby_points = df.iloc[indices].copy()
    nearby_points['distance'] = nearby_points.apply(lambda row: haversine(lat, lon, row['lat'], row['lon']), axis=1)
    return nearby_points[nearby_points['distance'] <= radius]

# Function to calculate the count and IDs of records within a 100000 meters radius for each record in the DataFrame
def calculate_nearby_counts(df, radius=100000):
    counts = []
    ids = []
    
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        nearby_points = points_within_radius_kdtree(row['lat'], row['lon'], radius)
        count = len(nearby_points) - 1  # Subtract 1 to exclude the point itself
        nearby_ids = nearby_points[nearby_points['ID'] != row['ID']]['ID'].tolist()  # Exclude the point itself
        counts.append(count)
        ids.append(nearby_ids)
    
    df['nearby_count'] = counts
    df['nearby_ids'] = ids
    return df

result_df = calculate_nearby_counts(df)
print(result_df)

Above code isn't giving me the intended results.
My independent output would be :



latitude
longitude
ID
#counts within 100000m
ids within 100000m




-22.582779
29.080456
0
2
[1,4]




As part of your [mre], would you have an expected output to go with that?

"Above code isn't giving me the intended results": As recommende in [ask], could you please describe the difficulty you are encountering?

Consider adding a tag about geography, such as geo

@OCa
My indented output df would be:
Latitude | Longitude | ID| #counts within 1000m | ID which are in 1000m radius|
29.6575 | 32.7789    | 11| 2                                    | [2, 7]

@Cba I have added as you suggested

No ID 8 in your input and points are spread out  with no distances under 1000m.

@Timeless it is a dummy input and output as I have 1 million records.

Ok but your expected output makes no sense. You can still make a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@Timeless, I have fixed it now have a look

You request 3 as a count while the list of ids has only 2. Also, the points 1 and 4 are at least 38 miles far away from point 0. I wonder why you insist on the 1000m constraint because it seems off.

@Timeless Hope, now it's super okay?

ok now may I ask again that you describe the issue. What is the issue with your code? Does it function without error yet return unexpected results?
This is probably the tree you are referring to: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html

It is giving me black results and counts as 0, all the time

This is the hard (and inefficient) way to do this. It's much easier to use GeoPandas which has all the spatial stuff built in for you. You want to use the dwithin function that does all of that directly.

Very useful suggestion. Could you also provide code which produces the expected result?
